# Is the ampersand sign a valid character for an Exchange email address?

Tags: email, exchange-server

I am trying to find out if the ampersand character "&" is a valid character for a Microsoft Exchange email address.  I know it is valid according to the RFC but I am thinking that exchange has a subset of valid characters.

Example:

Tom&Jerry@warnerbrothers.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, Exchange will handle those.

However, they take extra consideration when creating links on pages and other things that require encoding the email so Outlook and other clients understand what you intend.  It's probably best to avoid using them if possible.